# When do you reach a 'milestone'?

Tags: dnd-4e, terminology

The D&D 4th edition term 'milestone' isn't defined in the online D&D compendium, except that you gain an action point when it happens. When does a milestone occur? Has the definition changed since the game's initial release in 2008?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A milestone occurs after every two encounters (although the count is reset by taking an extended rest). Characters receive an action point and any other rewards the GM wishes to offer.

I don't have a DDI subscription, but this can be found on page 22 of the [Essentials Rules Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/247530000) and page 259 of the [Player's Handbook](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/217367200).

I don't remember it ever being defined differently.

Comment: Encounters don't necessarily mean combat either.  Skill challenges count too, and sometimes important role-play situations could be deemed encounters.

Comment: I believe there's some caveats that a DM can rule that particularly easy encounters don't count towards a milestone (or contrarywise, a particularly hard encounter can count as it's own milestone), but both options seemed a bit.. weaselly to me (as in, you probably should just fix your encounter difficulties).

Comment: Why "fix" your encounter difficulties? Not all encounters should be te same level of challenge, and it's reasonable for the milestone rules to acknowledge that.